# How to delete the duplicate in a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, duplicates

I'm trying to generate a Sudoku board via a 2D array: board[5][5]. The Sudoku board should only contain unique vowels. However, I have only made unique vowels appear in a row. For the columns, they still seem to have duplicates. How am I suppose to generate a column with no duplicates using the code I have so far?

Here's the code I have for generating unique letters in a row:

```
String [] vowels = {"A","E","I","O","U"};
String [][] board = new String [vowels.length][5];

public Actions(){
    int rows = 5;
    for(int row = 0;row<rows;row++){
        ArrayList<String> tempVowels = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(vowels));
        int numVowPerLine = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        for(int j = 0;j<numVowPerLine;j++){
            do{
                int pos = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
                if(board[row][pos] == null){
                    int temp = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*tempVowels.size());
                    board[row][pos] = tempVowels.get(temp);
                    tempVowels.remove(temp);
                    break;
                }   
            }while(true);
        }

    }
```

Credits to: L7ColWinters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a rather well known problem, called the [Rooks Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial#Rooks_problems).

Might I suggest a simpler loop?

EDIT: After reading comments, I see that the problem needs to be applied to each vowel. In my opinion, this is more readable:

```
java.util.Random random = new Random();

boolean[] r_occupied;
boolean[] c_occupied;

for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++)
  {
    // Clear the 'occupied' information
    r_occupied = new boolean[5];
    c_occupied = new boolean[5];

    // we will put vowel[i] 'count' times into the 'board'
    count = random.nextInt(5);

    for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
      {
        // generate a random row
        row = random.nextInt(5);

        // if it is already occupied, select the next one
        while (r_occupied[row])
          row = (row + 1) % 5;

        // generate a random column
        col = random.nextInt(5);

        // if it is already occupied, select the next one
        while (c_occupied[col])
          col = (col + 1) % 5;

        /* put the vowel at board[row][col] */
        r_occupied[row] = true;
        c_occupied[col] = true;
        board[row][col] = vowel[i];
      }
  }
```

Note: It will overwrite some vowels, but this should be OK.

Comment: hmm... i understand that with this code, the code would have no duplicate. Will the whole 2D array be filled up then?

Comment: Erm, the code fills 5 vowels into 5 correct slots on the 5x5 board. Isn't this what you were going for? Other positions remain empty for you to do what you want with them.

Comment: When I tried this code, it only shows one letter in a row and at the same in a column. My original problem was to replace the duplicate with null to erase the duplicate.

Comment: In the original code, the number of randomize number is also random. The vowels are also in a random order so there are always duplicate shown, and that's the problem.

Comment: @javaBeginner I did not understand what you mean. I cleaned up my code a bit, compiled and ran it. The program and its output are here: http://pastebin.com/aNzVUMSV ; How does this not fit what you want?

Comment: It randomly distributes 5 vowels into 5 rows/columns such that no two vowels occur on the same row/column. It leaves the other positions untouched, this is why they show up as null.

Comment: Oh... My problem is like this, the original problem is like this (http://www.fileserve.com/file/aCWjR8F/prob.JPG) see the picture, the code would put any number of random vowels into the 2D array inputted in a JButton, the problem is that there should be no duplicate in one column.

Comment: @javaBeginner - I can't see that image. The upload service only allows uploaders to view the image.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Just to clear things up a bit, I think what javaBeginner is trying to say is that she needs to generate vowels in EACH row without having duplicates in each COLUMN. Basically, you need to fill the whole board with AEIOU with no recurring vowels in a row and column.

Comment: As per comments, I have edited my answer with an outer loop. I think it is a little more readable than the original code, but loop depth is now the same.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/avwAzDzB - code that compiled cleanly for me, and a sample output.

Comment: @taeyeon Thanks! @javaBeginner - if you don't find enough vowels being generated, change `count = random.nextInt(5);` to something like `count = 2 + random.nextInt(3);`

Comment: @ArjunShankar I tried your code and it solved my problem. Thank you very much. I appreciate it very much. I have voted your answer. Thank you for you help again.

Comment: @ArjunShankar this is the sample output that you wanted to see...   (http://postimage.org/image/izl2pcvl1/) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before adding an additional vowel character in a row check if it
   already contains this vowel and with `continue` you can pass to the
   other vowel
2. You can also do the same thing for the columns with just switching
   it

before this:

```
board[row][pos] = tempVowels.get(temp);
```

Write this:

```
 boolean b = false;

    for(int j = 0;j<columnLength; j++){
        if(board[row][j] == tempVowels.get(temp))
            b= true;

        if(b == true)
        {
            b = false;
            continue;
        }
        board[row][pos] = tempVowels.get(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Does that mean that a checker should be checked within the row before continuing?

Comment: Because the problem is there are duplicates in the columns but not in the rows . . .

Comment: When I tried your code, I still got the same problem. Here's the proof (http://postimage.org/image/j0asubnjv/)

Comment: @Harout Hi, I tried your code and it also didn't work for me D:

Comment: you should substitute columnLength with  the real column length

Comment: @Harout - I tried that, is this the code that adds an additional vowel character in a row then checking if it already contains the same vowel and with continue you can pass to the other vowel?

Answer (score 0):

If the content of first column / first row is `A` and you are on the first column / second row, you could use a truncated array, i.e. `String [] availableVowels = {"E","I","O","U"};`, to select from. If you pick `O`, then when you are on first column / thrid row, you would choose from `String [] availableVowels = {"E","I","U"};`. etc.

Comment: What if the the whole of my board is already filled vowels? how will i be able to implement what you said?